# Is it possible to load/read shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat at compile time?

Tags: c++, file, memory-management, static-members, dlib

I am trying to build a **C++** application in *Visual Studio* using [DLIB](http://dlib.net/)'s [face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html). The build application run from command promt and trained model and image file is passed as arguments.

```
face_landmark_detection_ex.exe shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat image.jpg
```

this  `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` is the trained model for 68 landmarks to perform detection on input image and needs to load at run-time every time to perform any detection. I am trying to do following things.

- Load this  **shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat** at building the application or compile time.
- Read this **shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat** inside the code so that every time my application strarts its execution, it will not take more amount of memory.

Is there any way to pack this file inside my application so that it will take less physical memory to run.

**Update:**

How can I store this [shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat](http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2) file in a static buffer so that every time [shape_predictor](http://dlib.net/dlib/image_processing/shape_predictor.h.html) can read from this buffer.

Comment: What is the file content? What is its structure

Comment: @HumamHelfawi _shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat_ is the trained model after performing training using [train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp](http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.html). It is binary file basically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, its possible, but depends on Visual Studio and not cross-platform

1. You should create resource file and include hape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat into your project. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7zxb70x7.aspx for details. This will make compiler to put this file into your exe/dll
2. Open resoure at runtime and get memory pointer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719660(v=vs.85).aspx
3. Create memory stream (std::istream) from pointer.

   4. deserialize from this stream with dlib::deserialize

Here is minimal example, but without resource reading:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <dlib/image_processing/shape_predictor.h>


struct membuf : std::streambuf {
    membuf(char const* base, size_t size) {
        char* p(const_cast<char*>(base));
        this->setg(p, p, p + size);
    }
};
struct imemstream : virtual membuf, std::istream {
    imemstream(char const* base, size_t size)
            : membuf(base, size)
            , std::istream(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this)) {
    }
};
using namespace dlib; //its important to use namespace dlib for deserialize work correctly
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const char* file_name = "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat";
    ifstream fs(file_name, ios::binary | ios::ate);
    streamsize size = fs.tellg();
    fs.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    std::vector<char> buffer(size);
    if (fs.read(buffer.data(), size))
    {
        cout << "Successfully read " << size << " bytes from " << file_name << " into buffer" << endl;
        imemstream stream(&buffer.front(), size); // here we are loading from memory buffer. you can change this line to use pointer from Resource
        shape_predictor sp;
        deserialize(sp, stream);
        cout << "Deserialized shape_predictor" << endl;
    }
    else cout << "Failed to read " << file_name << " into buffer" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And about memory usage.

First of all you should know that shape_predictor::operator() is const, and the documentation says that is safe to use one shape_predictor for different threads.

So, you can create one shape_predictor at the start of program and use it many times, even from different threads

Next, putting shape predictor inside resource will make it be loaded into RAM when program starts, but deserializing it from resource will make copy of this memory, and this will lead to RAM usage overhead. If you need minimal possible RAM usage - you should load it from file

And the last your question - how to initialize it by compiler. There is no ready-to-use solution for it, but you can use the code from shape_predictor.h/deserialize function and load it manually. I think, this is bad solution, because you will not get less RAM usage compared to loading file

So my recommendation is to load one shape_predictor from file and use it globally for all threads

Comment: Is it possible to declare this memory membuff **static** and then every new shape_predictor object read/use this membuff as a sharable resource and do not increase memory consumption on creation of new objects.

Comment: how to deserialize memory stream to Shape_predictor Object

Comment: @VIctor, I have improved my answer. Hope, this will help you

Comment: thanks for your help ! I will use one shape_predictor globally.

Comment: What parts makes this VS only?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but a Visual Studio only solution would not have worked in my case since I am using `dlib` in Linux/macOS. Here is a Unix compatible solution that I came up with.

What I did was to use the [xxd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) tool to convert the model file into the `unsigned char []` representation of the file contents, write that into a custom header file, and use that inside `deserialize` (rather than read in the file during execution).

The following command would generate the header file for `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`:

```
xxd -i shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat > shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.hpp
```

If you look inside `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.hpp`, there will be 2 variables: `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks_dat` of type `unsigned char []` containing the contents of the model file and `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks_dat_len` of type `unsigned int`.

Inside your `dlib` driver code, you would do the following

```
...
#include "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.hpp"
...

shape_predictor sp;
std::stringstream landmarksstream;
landmarksstream.write((const char*)shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks_dat, shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks_dat_len);
deserialize(sp, landmarksstream);
```

**A word of warning: be careful about opening files generated by `xxd` because they can be quite large and cause your text editor to crash.**

I can't answer to the efficiency of this method, but it does allow for the model file to be "read in" at compile time rather than execution time.

Comment: What do you think of using mmap to load the models does it help reduce RAM usage and improves speed? Can the bytearray from an mmap feed into an `std::istream` without issues?

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer this question, but using `mmap` may very well be more efficient for all I know. My main concern when I came up with this solution was development velocity rather than the best implementation.